# Is it possible to read a pcap file from byte string with scapy?

Tags: python-3.x, scapy, pcap

I want to download a pcap from site.com/pcap.pcap, and determine if it has DNS records, using scapy. However, I don't want to ever write the file to disk. 
so something like

```
import requests
response=requests.get('site.com/pcap.pcap')
pcap_in_memory_as_bytes = response.content
some_scapy_func_that_finds_dns_traffic(pcap_in_memory_as_bytes)
```

Is it possible to do this with scapy? I tried a few things which seemed to fail. Searching for whether this was possible seemed to turn up nil.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `BytesIO` to read without storing the file locally

```
from scapy.utils import rdpcap
from io import BytesIO
pktpcap = rdpcap(BytesIO(response.content))
```

Afterwards you can check the file using for instance:

```
from scapy.layers.dns import *
for pkt in pktpcap:
    if DNS in pkt:
        .....
```